# Is it possible to set the OWN primary address in SCTP?

Tags: c, linux, sctp

I'm trying to set a SCTP connection between a server and clients (Linux). The server has several ip addresses and the outgoing ip packets are routed depending on the *source* addresss. I want the sctp connections use certain address by default (in order to use certain route by default)

The only options I have found are:

```
   SCTP_SET_PEER_PRIMARY_ADDR
          Requests that the peer mark the enclosed address as the association primary. The enclosed address must be one of the association's locally bound addresses. The struc‐
          ture sctp_setpeerprim defined in /usr/include/netinet/sctp.h is used to make a set peer primary request.

   SCTP_PRIMARY_ADDR
          Requests that the local SCTP stack use the enclosed peer address as the association primary. The enclosed address must be one of the association peer's addresses. The
          structure sctp_prim defined in /usr/include/netinet/sctp.h is used to make a get/set primary request.
```

As far as I understand, this options allow to select the peer's primary address (when sending)  and to ask the peer to use one of the local addresses (when receiving).

The quesion is: Is there a way to select the local address from which outgoing messages are sent?

Answer (score 0):

Chosing the interface, helps you?

You can use setsockopt for do that:

```
struct ifreq ifr;
strncpy_IFNAMSIZ(ifr.ifr_name, "ethX");
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &ifr, sizeof(ifr));
```

Comment: I could try that but wouldn't that disable the other interfaces (I have 1 address for each inerface btw). What I want to achieve is have the SCTP socket binded to  all the addresses/interfaces but select one in particular for sending messages

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not using lksctp's multipath or ASCONF stuff, but I've read the kernel module source.

A separate sctp_transport is built for each peer address, so things would depend on whether your local addrs are multipathed to one remote address, or two.

The association saves the destination address of received packets, for reuse as preferred source when sending over a particular sctp_transport.  Setting SCTP_SET_PEER_PRIMARY_ADDR would make the peer help you keep the right local address as the primary for a particular transport, and if there's only one transport, maybe you're done.  If there is more than one transport, it may make the peer pick a particular one. Setting SCTP_PRIMARY_ADDR is the flip case, and if there's more than one transport, it definitely updates which transport is primary.

For more than one transport, there isn't supposed to be a switch away from "primary" transport unless the the Upper Layer says to.  However, which transport is "active" depends on errors, etc, and for retransmits, the spec explicitly encourages using alternate transport addresses.  In general, I'd say it's pretty hopeless to try to control which transport is active (vs primary) at all times.  Simple things like sending INITs before the peer starts will toggle it back and forth.

Don't overlook the fact that if you bind/bindx to specific addresses (vs 0.0.0.0), it will only use those, in the case where you have addresses you absolutely don't want used.

I wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

sctp_sendmessage has the option. 
http://linux.die.net/man/3/sctp_sendmsg [SCTP_SendMessage][1]